# Signal (Int, Int) not recognised as (Int, Int) tuple in some cases

Tags: elm, elm-signal

Depending on the return type, Signal (Int, Int) is not recognised as a tuple of (Int, Int).

Consider the following code:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (..)
import Mouse


relativeMouseElement : (Int, Int) -> Element
relativeMouseElement mp = show (fst mp - 1000, snd mp - 1000)


relativeMouseTuple : (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
relativeMouseTuple mp = (fst mp - 1000, snd mp - 1000)

main =
--  Signal.map relativeMouse Mouse.position
    relativeMouseTuple Mouse.position
```

`Signal.map relativeMouse Mouse.position` works just fine, displays (-1000, -1000) to the browser and the values are adjusted according to the mouse movement.

`relativeMouseTuple Mouse.position` This though does not work. The complication error I get is the following:

```
Function `relativeMouseTuple` is expecting the argument to be:

    ( Int, Int )

But it is:

    Signal ( Int, Int )
```

I find this very weird. In both case the first argument is Signal (Int, Int) and in the second case it results to a type error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no experience with elm AT ALL, however:

`Signal.map` maps a function to a signal, this doesn't mean that the function is called with the `Signal` as a parameter, but that it is called with the signal's arguments as parameter. e.g. for `Signal(Int, Int)` you map a function that receives `(Int, Int)` as arguments.

So in the following case you have no problem

```
Signal.map relativeMouse Mouse.position
```

However, in the case below, you call a function that expects `(Int, Int)` with the argument `Signal(Int, Int)` which is wrong:

```
relativeMouseTuple Mouse.position
```

What you should do, is probably map your function to the Signal like this:

```
Signal.map relativeMouseTuple Mouse.position
```

Comment: That's a great answer for someone who has no experience with Elm :)

Comment: @MByD This is the definition of `map : (a -> result) -> Signal a -> Signal result` which is spot on with what you described as part of your answer.